# Grunt error with fs.unlinkSync on Sails

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I'm using skipper to receive the files, sharp to resize (and save) and fs unlink to remove the old image. But I got a very weird error this time that concerns me a lot:

> error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
>   error: 
>   Aborted due to warnings.
>   Running "copy:dev" (copy) task
>   Warning: Unable to read "assets/images/users/c8e303ca-1036-4f52-88c7-fda7e01b6bba.jpg" file (Error code: ENOENT).
>
> error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
>   error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
>   error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.
>
> error: Troubleshooting tips:
>   error: 
>   error:  *->  Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
>   error: 
>   error:  *->  You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
>   error: 
>   error:  *->  Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
>   error:      e.g., `(edited for privacy)/sails/.tmp` ?
>   error: 
>   error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
>   error:      sudo chown -R 1000 (edited for privacy)/sails/.tmp

Grunt stopped running and to have that in production is a big NoNo... I believe that this is caused because of concurrency with fs.unlinkSync(fname). The error is also intermittent and very hard to reproduce in some machines (IO ops/sec maybe?).

I have the following controller action:

```
var id = 1; // for example

req.file('avatar').upload({
    dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/images')
}, function(err, files){
    var avatar = files.pop();

    //file name operations here. output is defined as the path + id + filetype
   //...

    sharp(avatar.fd)
    .resize(800, 800)
    .toFile(output, (err, info)=>{
        if(err){
            res.badRequest();
        } else {
            fs.unlinkSync(avatar.fd);
            res.ok();
        }
    });
});
```

Now I've been thinking about a few solutions:

1. Output the new image directly to `.temp`
2. Unlink when files exists on `.tmp`. Explanation: Grunt already copied the old file so  removing it would be safe!

But I don't know if this is some spaghetti code or even if a better solution exists.

EDIT: My solution was, as proposed by arbuthnott, wrap a controller like this:

```
get : function(req, res){
    var filepath = req.path.slice(1,req.path.length);
    //remove '/' root identifier. path.resolve() could be used

    if(fs.existsSync(path.resolve(filepath))){
        return res.sendfile(filepath);
    } else {
        return res.notFound();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track about the error. You are making some rapid changes to in the assets folder. If I read your code right:

1. Add an image with user-generated filename to `assets/images` (ex `cat.jpg`)
2. Copy/resize the file to an id filename in `assets/images` (ex `abc123.jpg`)
3. Delete the original upload (`cat.jpg`)

(I don't know the details of sharp, there may be more under the hood there)

If sails is running in dev mode, then Grunt will be trying to watch the whole `assets/` folder, and copy all the changes to `.tmp/public/`. It's easy to imagine Grunt may register a change, but when it gets around to copying the added file (`assets/images/cat.jpg`) it is already gone.

---

I have two suggestions for the solution:

One:

Like you suggested, upload your original to the `.tmp` folder (maybe even a custom subfolder of `.tmp`). Still place your sized copy into `/assets/images/`, and it will be copied to `/.tmp/public/` where it can be accessed as an asset by the running app. But Grunt will ignore the quick add-then-delete in the `.tmp` folder.

Two:

Do a bit of general thinking about both what you want to include in version control, and what Grunt tasks you want to be running in production. Note that if you use `sails lift --prod` then Grunt watch is turned off by default, and this error would not even occur. Generally, I don't feel like we want Grunt to do too much in production, it is more of a development shortcut. Specifically, Grunt watch can use a lot of resources on a production server.

The note about version control is just that you probably want some of the contents of `assets/images/` to be in version control (images used by the site, etc), but maybe not in the case of user-uploaded avatars. Make sure you have a way to differentiate these contents (subdirectories or whatever). Then they can be easily `.git-ignore`'d or whatever is appropriate.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: From bottom to top. I'm making a big bucket folder for users images in `assets/images/users/` and `".gitignoring"` everything (except the `.gitkeep`). You are right about Grunt in prod, but I need to manually copy each avatar to './tmp' then?
About solution one, yeah, I think it will do the trick.

Comment: I've gotten in the habit of keeping all non-version controlled media outside the assets folder, and filtering all requests for it through a specifically written method in a `MediaController` (using `res.sendfile`). It's a pain in some ways, but we've been using it now for over a year, and I recommend it.

Comment: That's a good solution for hiding stuff behind policies and etc. and I'm actually doing that for restricted files. But I think it is overkill to simple images... I don't know, I guess I need to spend more time thinking about this...

Comment: Hey, just a feedback, I did the Controller (it hurts my simple dev heart). For now it is the best  solution to keep me from using Grunt in prod and also have a good folder structure... It is just a 4 lines controller and it is working as expected. Ty asbuthnott!!!

Comment: Great. You may be glad if you ever want to do complicated things - put policies on media, allow sizing options, provide fallback default images, etc. Like I said, we started doing it this way a year ago, and haven't had to touch the methods since.